# Condition compilation is turned off

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the code in Razor and `reloadInterva`l is always 0 on prod server, on dev server I get correct value. Also `@TimeSpan` gives error in intellisense like **Condition compilation is turned off**. Why I get this error and zero instead of actual value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var reloadInterval = @TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds;
    setInterval(LoadResultForm, reloadInterval);

    function LoadResultForm() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ResultForm", "File")',            
            data: '',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ResultForm').html(data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just assign it to **2000**? It'd be *much less* confusing.

Comment: This is just an example.